# Java: How to represent 1d string/int array into 2d int array?

Tags: java, arrays

// Java: How to represent 1d string/int array into 2d int array? I would really appreciate your help.

```
package intro;
public class ArrayTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[][]= new int[4][4];   
        int month_days [] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31,13,14,15,16};

        int size =4;
        //System.out.println(size);
        for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < size; i++, k++) {
            for(int j=0; j <size; j++){
                arr[i][j]= month_days[k++];

                //System.out.println(month_days[k++] + " ");
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 31 28 31 30 
30 31 31 30 
30 31 13 14 
16 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16
 at intro.ArrayTest.main(ArrayTest.java:13)

Comment: Learn to use debugging tools.

Comment: What line is number 13?  `ArrayTest.java:13` refers to the class (`ArrayTest.java`) and line number (`13`) in which the error occurs.

Comment: You are incrementing k in two places. (And three if you uncomment the print statement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You increment `k` too often. You increment it in the for-loop and here: `month_days[k++]`.
Remove the increment from the for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < size; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `arr[i][j] = month_days[k++];` to `arr[i][j] = month_days[k];`

Every instance of `k++` is incrementing k by 1.  Currently, you're incrementing it twice per iteration of your `for` loop, so after the 8th iteration, it's looking to put the 17th element of `month_days[]` into `arr[][]`, but `month_days[]` doesn't have that many elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are already incrementing your 'k' variable in this line:
month_days[k++];

You don't need to increment it in this line as well:
for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < size; i++, **k++**) {

Basically, you are throwing away a 'k' value each time your loop runs, which makes you run out of values before you can fill your array.